# How to prepare json file from feature file?

Tags: json, rest, cucumber, bdd

Is there any way to prepare json file from .feature file in BDD?

I am trying to create json file where input source of data is .feature file

```
Feature: Testing a REST API 
       Scenario: Create student account using post method
       Given api is up and running for post method
       When i create json with below valuesand hit rest api

 | Student_id            |Name       |   CityName    | State  |PostCode    |Tel            |
 |      0101             |Andrew     |  Leeds        |        | SO143FT    | 345345345345  |
 |      0102             |Smith      |  NewCastle    |        | SO143LN    | 345345345345  |
       Then Status is 201
```

Below is the sample json file.

```
      {
            "Student_id": 0101,
            "Name": "test",
            "CityName": "test",
            "State": "TT",
            "PostCode": 89098,
            "Tel": "(000)- 000-0000",

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Found solution for my problem: table is datatable in cucumber.

```
 List<String> jsons = table.asMaps(String.class, String.class)

.stream()
.map(gson::toJson)
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a class Student with the desired fields (as in your Example table) and you can use a framework like jackson to create json from that class.

```
@JsonTypeInfo(include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT, use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME)
@JsonNaming(value = PropertyNamingStrategy.UpperCamelCaseStrategy.class)
public class Student {
        int student_id;
        String name;
        String cityName;
        String state;
        int PostCode; //Note: your example has an int, but might be a String actually?
        String Tel;
}

public Student(int student_id, String name, String cityName, String     state, int PostCode, String Tel) {
    this.student_id = student_id;
    this.name = name;
    this.cityName = cityName;
    this.state = state;
    this.PostCode = PostCode;
    this.Tel = PostCode;
}
```

You'll need to update the Scenario Outline to take the values from the Examples-table. For instance, in Cucumber you could do the following:

`When I create a student with <Student_id> and <Name> in <CityName> in <State> with <PostCode> and <Tel>`

The variables marked with <> will be replaced with the values from the table.

You would then implement a StepDefinition where you create a new Student with these values. I've added a Constructor to the Student class.

You'll then need to create the http call to send the created student as Json.

To post the http call you can use a framework like RestAssured.
Afaik RestAssured does not take objects, so you'lL have to generate the json from the object.

Here's an [example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/) of how to do that with jackson.

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Student student = new Student(student_id, name, cityName, state, PostCode, Tel);

//Object to JSON in String
String jsonInString = mapper.writeValueAsString(user);

Then use `jsonInString` in your http call.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Is it possible for you to provide me sample code?

Comment: I've updated the answer. Is this sufficient for you, or do you need more? (if so, please be specific)

Comment: Yes Would be great if you provide me complete solution. i am using serenity rest assured only. I am trying to solve this issue from long time but still facing issue.

Comment: @Dipak I cannot provide you a complete solution, as my experience with Serenity is limited. I've expanded the answer above; let me know how far you can get on your own with this and post updates if you have further questions.

Comment: Thank you for valuable response but don't you think if you have table with 10 or more columns in that case feature file will look very ugly.

Comment: Yes, it might. But would you actually use all 10 or more fields for each test case? Or could some fields be set with a default value?

Comment: Alternatively you could create different scenarios where you would place the variables directly in the steps (to prevent a table with 10+ columns).

Comment: I dot think so its good  because i want to prepare json and without any missing fields it will give me error