# Can we do parametrize for test using JSON file?

Tags: protractor

Currently I am building my custom test framework using Protractor with  Cucumber.But I want to read the data from external JSON file instead of reading it from feature file, is there anyway available to achieve it?

Here I want to read the value from JSON file and not from feature file

Comment: Can you add some more details and code snippets? Have a look on how to ask an MCVE [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prepare json file from feature file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48487298/how-to-prepare-json-file-from-feature-file)

Comment: Try looking into [params](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/e77885d7a60fd5a56bf624a5307fd41582f10bca/lib/config.ts#L517). You can put them in an external file and just `require` that file in your config.